# SQL Server Query problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wanted so much help from you guys :( ok, my problem is how to create a query that satifies my needs.. I have 3 Tables namely `TableA(ColID, ColName, ColRec)`, `TableB (ColRec, bID)`, and `TableC(bID, xGrade, xTake, ColID)`.

**Sample Record**

[image]

When I search for the `ColID` from `TableA` I want to display all `xGrade` from `TableC` like this below:

[image]

but instead of above result I get this:

[image]

It also displays all records that matches `bID` from `TableB` and `bID` from `TableC`.

I can't finish my project without this query :( please help me guys..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @rsbarro : i got result from other record from TableA but display ColID the same as the searched ColID

Comment: can you edit the title of the post, it's currently next to useless as "SQL Server Query problem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    A.ColID, B.bID, C.xGrade 
FROM 
    TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ColRec =  B.ColRec 
LEFT JOIN 
    TableC C on B.bID = C.bID AND A.ColID = C.ColID 
WHERE 
    A.ColID  = 1
```

will that work?

Comment: yes that worked, but it lacks record from TableC. i want to still display record of A4 (NULL Value) from TableB even if it doesn't exist on tableC.

Comment: the left join should take care of that

Comment: left join displays xGrade from other record of ColID from tableA as long as it matches bid from TableB anc TableC

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @johntotetwoo: Why would you think so? Did you try it? The query seems fine to me. I was about to post my solution, but then I realised it was same as this one. Otherwise you might have missed out some important detail when describing your problem.